# Numpy structured array with datetime

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to build a structured array with a datetime coloumn

```
import numpy as np
na_trades = np.zeros(2, dtype = 'datetime64,i4')
na_trades[0] = (np.datetime64('1970-01-01 00:00:00'),0)

TypeError: Cannot cast NumPy timedelta64 scalar from metadata [s] to  according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify that the `datetime64` is in seconds when you create the array because the one you parse and try to assign is a `datetime64[s]`:

```
na_trades = np.zeros(2, dtype='datetime64[s],i4')
na_trades[0] = (np.datetime64('1971-01-01 00:00:00'), 0)
```

The error you get means that the `datetime64` object that you specified is not `same_kind` as the one you try to assing. You try to assign a seconds resolution one, and you created a different one when you constructed the array (by default I think it's nanoseconds).

Comment: What versin of NumPy do you use? it works perfectly for me with NumPy 1.7.1.

Comment: In 1.6.2, it raises ValueError. In 1.7.1, it work perfect. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
>>> na_trades = np.zeros(2, dtype=[('dt', 'datetime64[s]'), ('vol', 'i4')])
>>> na_trades
array([(datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), 0),
       (datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), 0)], 
      dtype=[('dt', ('<M8[s]', {})), ('vol', '<i4')])
>>> na_trades[0] = (np.datetime64('1970-01-02 00:00:00'),1)
>>> na_trades
array([(datetime.datetime(4707, 11, 29, 0, 0), 1),
       (datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), 0)], 
      dtype=[('dt', ('<M8[s]', {})), ('vol', '<i4')])
```

Comment: Actually on 1.7.1 your code raises the exception `TypeError: Cannot cast NumPy timedelta64 scalar from metadata [s] to  according to the rule 'same_kind'` You should update to a new version because the old style of managing datetimes is obsolete in the 1.7.x version of NumPy [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

Comment: @ViktorKerkez, I updated the code and confirmed that it work on 1.7.1. Thank you for comment.